# How can I simplify this GROUPING SETS query into a ROLLUP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, rollup

I'm trying to create a `SELECT` statement to calculate multiple levels of subtotals across two hierarchies. I have a `Geo` hierarchy which consists in `region` and `department`, and a `Time` hierarchy which consists in `month` and `quarter`.

At the moment, I have three tables which have the following structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Sales(
    Time_id Date NOT NULL,
    Geo_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    Prod_id CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    sales INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Time_id, Geo_id, Prod_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Time(
    Time_id Date NOT NULL,
    month CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    quarter CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    year CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Time_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Geo(
   Geo_id CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
   city   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   dept   CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
   region CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(Geo_id)
);
```

I wrote the following query that returns me the right values (63 rows):

```
SELECT
    Geo.region, Geo.dept, Time.month, Time.quarter, SUM(Sales.sales) AS sales
FROM
    Geo, Sales, Time
WHERE
    Sales.Time_id = Time.Time_id AND Sales.Geo_id = Geo.Geo_id
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS(
        (Geo.dept, Time.month),
        (Geo.dept, Time.quarter),
        (Geo.region, Time.month),
        (Geo.region, Time.quarter),
        Geo.dept,
        Geo.region,
        Time.month,
        Time.quarter,
        () -- thanks to @Larnu
    )
```

I find my query to be really repetitive and I think there is a **better way** of doing it using `ROLLUP`. Can anyone please help me to simplify it, as I'm relatively new to `SQL` analytics?

Comment: You need the grouping set `()` to a grand total.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your answer. Do you know any way of simplifying it using `ROLLUP`?

Comment: GROUPING SETS and related syntax was introduced so you could do more complex things than ROLLUP could. I don’t think you can simplify the _query_ without also changing / limiting the results

Comment: (And if you want to make the query more readable, I'd shift focus away from not liking the GROUPING SETS to fixing that 1982 "join" (`FROM Geo, Sales, Time`) and [write a proper join instead](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Looks like you could use `CUBE` but it's likely to be more confusing, not less, and will not be any more performant